# «Пушкин»/«пушкин»

Tags: прописная-строчная

С какой буквы написать это слово в этом предложении:

`Вот это я п-/Пушкин, конечно.`

Слово *пушкин* не в значении фамилии поэта, а в значении *поэт*.

То есть слово *поэт* в данном случае будет тождественно этому слову, то есть не в прямом смысле Пушкин. Поэтому вопрос и возник.

Как думаете, совы?

Comment: С большой буквы. Ведь ты же говоришь Пушкин, а не Гомер или Маяковский, значит намекаешь на качество пушкинской поэзии, а не какой-то еще. Я (как) Пушкин.

Comment: Слово _Пушкин_ равно слову _поэт_! Это одни и те же по значению слова — ни больше ни меньше — в моем предложении! Я не называю себя Александром Сергеевичем Пушкиным, я называю себя поэтом в общем. Понимаете, о чем я говорю?

Comment: Не особо, можешь другой привести пример? Я так понимаю, что если речь идет о качестве - то это персонификация, значит с большой. поэт => Пушкин, а Пушкин => Поэт - настоящий поэт, настоящий - качество.